# what does "NYI" refer to in the comments of OpenCascade source code

Tags: opencascade

I noticed it first in [`BRepCheck_Analyzer.hxx`](https://github.com/Open-Cascade-SAS/OCCT/blob/master/src/BRepCheck/BRepCheck_Analyzer.hxx):

```cpp
class BRepCheck_Analyzer 
{
public:

  DEFINE_STANDARD_ALLOC

  //! Constructs a shape validation object defined by the shape S.
  //! <S> is the  shape  to control.  <GeomControls>  If
  //! False   only topological informaions  are checked.
  //! The geometricals controls are
  //! For a Vertex :
  //! BRepCheck_InvalidToleranceValue  NYI
  //! For an Edge :
  //! BRepCheck_InvalidCurveOnClosedSurface,
  //! BRepCheck_InvalidCurveOnSurface,
  //! BRepCheck_InvalidSameParameterFlag,
  //! BRepCheck_InvalidToleranceValue  NYI
```

and my guess is "Not Yet Implemented", but it appears [throughout the code base](https://github.com/Open-Cascade-SAS/OCCT/search?q=NYI) and some cases those make less sense for those references.  It comes up a lot in french comments, maybe it's something else in that language, or it's an author's initials?

For example, `BRepCheck_InvalidToleranceValue` is noted as `NYI` above, but it does [seem to be used](https://github.com/Open-Cascade-SAS/OCCT/blob/ae38730d3520fc8d0fbe4a3b9a97afd0cebe6df8/src/BRepCheck/BRepCheck_Analyzer.cxx#L255).

Answer (score 1):

I guess that you are pretty right in your assumptions - NYI over the code looks like somebody's acronym / nickname:

> // NYI 971219 : on ne tient pas compte de l'orientation de E = arete-mere de l'interference I
> ...
> // NYI XPU: 16-05-97: INTPATCH -> the parametrization of a point on a
> // periodized curve is INSUFFICIENT : parVP on line can be either 0.
> // or period.

Before wide adoption of modern code versioning systems like SVN/git, it was a common practice to put an acronym, bug number and date of modifications into the code.

These comments might be 20+ years old, so it would be difficult and not very  useful to figure out who might be a real author.

Comment: thanks for looking!  and that's how I made sense of it as well.  initial import into git looks like it was [back in 2012](https://git.dev.opencascade.org/gitweb/?p=occt.git;a=commit;h=7fd59977dfb3a75f75670474b59dfc0f3f5f90ba) with development looking as though it starts properly in 1991. some older fortran code was converted to C++ in `AdvApp2Var_MathBase.cxx`, and some comments suggest first pieces were december 1990

Comment: Git was truncated from OCCT 6.5.0 release. So that a lot of history is lost behind (considering that at some point it was a closed-source project, and versioning tools were worse before git).